# duplicate node issue in my Linq to Xml query

Tags: linq-to-xml

I've managed to query an XML document from a file, however I only need to pull just one "filter" node from this XML snippet (along with its child nodes of course) based on the "id" which is passed into my C# method:

```
  <outBound>
   <body>
       <filter id="1">
          <name>A. All Portfolios</name>
          ...
          <query>
              ...
          </query>
       </filter>
       <filter id="2">
          <name>A. Busines Portfolios</name>
          ...
          <query>
              ...
          </query>
       </filter>
   </body>
  </outBound>
```

I modeled my L2X code from some MS samples I downloaded, but how would I simply pull filter only ?

```
        XDocument document = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/xml/portfolioFilters.xml"));  //portfolioFiltersResponse  //portfolioFilters            
        var portFilterAll = from x in document.Descendants()
                         where x.Name == "filter"
                         select x;

        var portFilt = new XElement("filter",
                            from x in document.Descendants("filter")
                            where (string)x.Element("name") == filterName
                            select new XElement("filter",
                                        x.Attribute("id"),
                                        x.Element("name"),
                                        x.Element("type"),
                                        x.Element("userId"),
                                        x.Element("security"),
                                        x.Element("queries")
                                       ));
```

However, what I'm getting as my final result is an EXTRA "filter" node on top like this:

```
   <filter>
     <filter id="1">
       <name>A. All Portfolios</name>
       ...
       <query>
          ...
       </query>
     </filter>
   </filter>
```

Can someone help me in tweaking this a bit to only pull the "filter" node I need, based on the "id" attribute ?

thank you.
Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a top level filter element and select and create a child filter element. 
How about just selecting what you need like this:

```
var portFilt = from x in document.Descendants("filter")
               where (string)x.Element("name") == filterName
               select x;
```

Comment: var pfFilter = from x in document.Descendants()
                             where 
                             x.Name == "filter" &&
                             x.Element("name").Value.Equals(filterName)
                             select x;

Comment: Usually just formatting it right will highlight it. If you need more details take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting. I fixed the query by adding `select x;` - you want to use `(string)x.Element("name")` instead of `x.Element("name").Value` to avoid NullReferenceExceptions if the element with name does not exist. (to mark code inline you use the backtick (`))

Comment: and now that portFilt has just one clean <filter> node, how do I convert that xml into a string so I can return to caller ?

Comment: No, actually it shows a value of '  pfFilter.ToString() "System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1[System.Xml.Linq.XElement]" string
'

Comment: this seems to work though: <!-- language: c# -->            foreach (XElement filt in pfFilter)
            {
                xmlfilter = filt.ToString();
                name = filt.Element("name").ToString();
            }

Comment: This is because the query was not evaluated. You can do foreach as you did or - if you expect just one element you could do `portFilt.Single().ToString();`